# How to get a percentage of a column based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

The SQLite database is [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

The question I have is Which countries have the highest sales revenue? What percent of total revenue does each country make up?

I have already solved the first part of the question. But I can't solve the second question.

Here's my code:

```
 SELECT invoices.BillingCountry, SUM(invoice_items.UnitPrice * invoice_items.Quantity) Total
FROM invoices
JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.InvoiceId = invoices.InvoiceId
GROUP BY invoices.BillingCountry
ORDER BY SUM(invoice_items.UnitPrice * invoice_items.Quantity) DESC;
```

How can I solve the question 'What percent of total revenue does each country make up?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
SELECT 
    i.BillingCountry, 
    SUM(ii.UnitPrice * ii.Quantity) Total,
    SUM(ii.UnitPrice * ii.Quantity) / SUM(SUM(ii.UnitPrice * ii.Quantity)) OVER() Ratio
FROM invoices i
JOIN invoice_items ii ON ii.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
GROUP BY i.BillingCountry
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

The window `sum()` gives you the `sum()` of each country's sales over the whole dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much! What does the OVER() function do?

Comment: @SakirInteser: this is a window function... see [the official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).